# Animated Curve Modifier + Cycles Motion Blur = Weird Render Artifacts

Tags: rendering, modifiers, bezier-curves, artifacts, motion-blur

I'm trying to render an animation which involves two animated objects which have curve modifiers attached to them. After making a test render, I found some odd render artifacts, and I was hoping there's just some button I need to push to make this look normal.

I have done some tests and it appears the artifacts won't show up if I disable motion blur, but I want to leave it enabled for this animation.

[Here's the animation](https://gfycat.com/gifs/BothUnfortunateAustraliancattledog)

And here's a still frame where the artifacts are clearly visible:
[image: Frame0030]

Comment: Possibly overlapping geometry causing z-fighting. Check for overlapping faces or meshes - even if set to be transparent.

Comment: @RichSedman just checked for that, and I even tried applying the curve modifier during one of the problematic frames, and it seems to be clean geometry :(

Comment: Can you share your .blend - perhaps someone can spot something.